# I want pass an array object as an parameter to another page through routing my function is as follows

Tags: angular, angular-routing

```
Goto(item)
{

    console.log(item.numtopics);
    this.router.navigate(['/numbersystem'],  { queryParams: item.numtopics});

}
```

and getting the data as follows

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe( param => {


        console.log(param);
    });

    }
```

but in console I am getting data like this

```
{0: "[object Object]", 1: "[object Object]", 2: "[object Object]"}
```

I am not getting the array data properly

Answer (score 0):

`queryParams` are URL parameters. Which means they need to be strings.

You can't pass dynamic data through your router. If you want to do so, you need to use a sharing service, as explained in [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

Console.log() accepts string as parameter .If you want to print array data on console try
console.log(JSON.stringify(params))...this would give what you are looking for